# Comment on others' questions

Tags: discussion, comments

How can one comment on others' questions on AskUbuntu, is there a rep limit to it?
The reason why I'm asking this (and there might be a similar question already, but I couldn't find it), is that at times, I'd like to post a comment on some questions for say something along the lines of further clarification, but that option is never there. At the same time there are members with a high rep, who do have the aforementioned option enabled because I've seen them comment on questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a rep requirement:

[/privileges/comment](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment)

> Please note that you can *always* comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions. However, commenting on *other people's* posts is a privilege.

It requires **50 reputation**.

Once you have gained the privilege, you will get the same commenting function as on your own posts.